# How to put ripple effect on all elements in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like that `highlightColor` also take the Text and not only the background of the Material

```
Container(
  height: 75.0,
  width: double.infinity,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
  child: Material(
    color: Colors.grey.shade400,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          onTap: (){},
          highlightColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          customBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0))),
        const Center(
          child: Text(
            'Ceci est un texte',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Colors.black
            )
          )
        )
      ]
    )
  )
)
```

**If you have a solution!**

Answer (score 0):

remove `Stack` widget and assign the `Text` widget as a `child` of `InkWell`.

```
Container(
  height: 75.0,
  width: double.infinity,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
  child: Material(
    color: Colors.grey.shade400,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      highlightColor: Colors.green,
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      customBorder:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
      child: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'Ceci est un texte',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```